# Building LDAP Query that removes groups in a different domain

Tags: sharepoint, active-directory, ldap

I need to build a query that pulls in all users with the *domain.com that are inactive.

```
(&(userPrincipalName=*domain.com)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)
```

This is no problem, the problem is that there is another domain that has groups that are named the same as the production groups. So i tried something like this and it didn't work. I am trying to pull in the groups that are not in the dev domain.

```
(&(objectcategory=group)(!(ou:dn:=dev)))
```

I've also tried

```
(&(objectcategory=group)(!cn=dev.top.domain.com))
```

Edit: There are two potential ways to do Active Directory within the SharePoint tool. "ActiveDirectoryCustomQuery" and "ActiveDirectoryCustomFilter". I'm using the latter.

Comment: The search domain is typically specified before you even get to a point where you can run an LDAP query. What method are you using to access Active Directory?

Comment: I only have access to LDAP queries. This is through SharePoint. Are there any other ways to get a group? The only difference is the distinguished name, and the domain it's in. Sorry, I also don't know much about AD. It seems like those are the only two differences. There was another option for the Query. Maybe thats what you are talking about

Comment: Updating my Question